# Tab stop across multiple lines so that text fills in the dots leader instead of moving down the lines

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

In word, I have a form type of document, and a field called "description" has a couple of lines to give space to write text (as you would see on a printed document).

I create a dotted line using dots leader in tab stops. However, using the tab stops on each line, results in this behavior:

[image: Lines are getting pushed down instead of filled in]

As you can see, when the content is larger than one line, the tab stops below just get pushed down. However, I wanted them to get filled in just like the first line like the example below:
[image: The correct way]

I've tried using soft breaks and removing the breaks but these ways didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to limit the user to just those 3 lines?  If so, you could enclose your Description and tabs in a table without borders, and set its row height to exactly whatever height fits your 3 dotted lines.  That way, the dotted lines will get "hidden" as text is added by being pushed down as they are currently are and so won't be seen by the table as it's row height won't automatically adjust to fit the extra text.

Comment: Ah thank you, another hack but that's not a bad idea!